# how to display checked state in a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using this code to make checkboxes visible based on name. But if I use controls I can't check if checkbox is checked(because I want to show checkbox in a checked state).

My code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Program.productOperationCount; i++)
        {
            
            this.Controls.Find($"checkBox{i + 1}", true)[0].Visible = true;
        }
```

I need something like this, but there is no method for it:

```
this.Controls.Find($"checkBox{i + 1}", true)[0].Checked = true;
```

Comment: You need to cast the find result as a `CheckBox`

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

try like this.

```
      foreach (var checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            if (checkBox.Checked == true && checkBox.Name =="cbname")
            {
               //do stuff
            }
                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to navigate the form controls and a control variable to count the checkbox controls.

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
{
     if(this.Controls[i] is CheckBox)
     {
         CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)this.Controls.Find($"checkBox{j + 1}", true)[0];
         chk.Checked = true;
         j++;
     }
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var ctr in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctr is CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ctr;
        chk.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Form is a Control. Every Control has a property Controls which is of type ControlCollection. ControlCollection implements IList, which Implements IEnumerable.

And that's when we start thinking LINQ.

Whenever you have an object that implements IEnumerable, then this object represents a sequence of fairly similar items. To get all items in this sequence of class `MyClass`, use [Enumerable.OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0)

```
include System.Linq;

private IEnumerable<CheckBox> CheckBoxes => this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```

In words: to get all CheckBoxes in my collection of Controls, get the value of property `this.Controls`, which implements IEnumerable. From this sequence, keep only thos Controls that are of type CheckBox (or derived types).

To get all checked Checkboxes:

```
private IEnumerable<CheckBox> CheckedCheckBoxes => this.CheckBoxes
    .Where(checkBox => checkBox.Checked);
```

In words: to get all checked CheckBoxes, get the value of property `this.CheckBoxes`, which represents an enumerable sequence of CheckBoxes. From this sequence of CheckBoxes, keep only those CheckBoxes that have a true value for property Checked.

Answer (score -1):

you should make a custom class that contains the object that you want and a `bool` called `_checked`. that easy !

A class like :

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ExampleWithBoolHAHAHAHA
{
    public bool _checked = false;
    public object yourObjectInHere;
}
```

Comment: This is... odd?